# Error from my eclipse plugin project

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

The type of org.osgi.services.event.Event cannot be resolved . It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

Comment: so what is your question?

Comment: Need more information.  Stack trace would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Add the jar that conains org.osgi.services.event.Event to your classpath in Eclipse.  The possible jars are listed [here](http://www.jarfinder.com/index.php/java/info/org.osgi.service.event.Event)

Answer (score 0):

You need to do the following:

1. Open up your project's MANIFEST.MF
2. In the multipage manifest editor go to the dependencies tab
3. Click "add..."
4. Select `org.eclipse.osgi.services` as the bundle to add
5. Save and wait for the build to complete.